# Server.Transfer and F12 tool : How to know which page is loaded?

Tags: asp.net

When using Server.Transfer in an ASP.NET web page

How to know which page is loaded using F12 tool ?  I'm always wondering what I see on screen since the URL doesn't change it's hard to know in which page the content I'm looking is located exactly.

Comment: You can't. Server.Transfer happens entirely on the server, there is no request from the browser, all you see is the HTML of the response.

Comment: Look at the server code on the loaded page and follow the logic.  Or if you get desperate, inspect a button or element and copy the ID of the control, search project for that name (usually the last part of the ID for server controls).

Comment: Well I know how to find out using all kind of workarounds but I'm asking with the F12 tool of the browsers.  If there's no way I will forfeit but for now I will wait for an answer to that question.

Thank you.